# Replace a Pandas column of list with corresponding dict values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dict` and `dataframe` like this.

```
dct = {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c',4:'d'}

df = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "id":[1,2,3],
    "vals":[[1,2,3],[2,4,2],[1,3,2]]
}
)
```

The dataframe I want

```
    id  vals
0   1   [a, b, c]
1   2   [b, d, b]
2   3   [a, c, b]
```

Current approach

```
final = []

for row in df.itertuples():

    new = []

    for i in range(len(row.vals)):
        new.append(dct[row.vals[i]])

    final.append({'id': row.id,'vals': new})

df = pd.DataFrame(final)
```

Is there any better and fast way to do it?. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dct = {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c',4:'d'}
```

Try with `apply()` and list comprehension:

```
df['vals']=df['vals'].apply(lambda x:[dct[y] for y in x])
```

Output of `df`:

```
    id  vals
0   1   [a, b, c]
1   2   [b, d, b]
2   3   [a, c, b]
```

Comment: The data frame has 20L rows daily and with more than 20 elements in each row. It's kind of shipment data. Exploding is not a good option though

Comment: updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: I think for performnace this is good solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can try explode the series, map the values, then aggregate back:

```
df['vals'] = (df['vals'].explode()
               .map(dct)
               .groupby(level=0)
               .agg(list)
             )
```

Output:

```
   id       vals
0   1  [a, b, c]
1   2  [b, d, b]
2   3  [a, c, b]
```